# zoom not working if I try to pinch within the textview

Tags: java, android, scrollview, pinchzoom

I'm trying to implement pinch to zoom for TextView. The zoom and scroll work fine if I keep the content width and height as wrap content i.e pinch to zoom works when I do it outside the TextView, but does not work if done within the TextView.

I want to do it within the TextView. i.e when the width and height are set to match parent.

Here is my code:

Activity code:

```
public class sukharta extends Activity {

TextView scaleGesture;
RelativeLayout relative;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sukharta);
    scaleGesture = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.article);
    scaleGesture.setText(R.string.twentyfive);
    relative = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.sv) ;

    // ******Set gesture on your TextView******
    relative.setOnTouchListener(new simpleOnScaleGestureListener(this));

}


public class simpleOnScaleGestureListener implements View.OnTouchListener,
        ScaleGestureDetector.OnScaleGestureListener {

    private ScaleGestureDetector relative;

    public simpleOnScaleGestureListener(Context context) {
        relative = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        relative = detector;

        float size = scaleGesture.getTextSize();
        Log.d("TextSizeStart", String.valueOf(size));

        float factor = detector.getScaleFactor();
        Log.d("Factor", String.valueOf(factor));


        float product = size * factor;
        Log.d("TextSize", String.valueOf(product));
        scaleGesture.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, product);

        size = scaleGesture.getTextSize();
        Log.d("TextSizeEnd", String.valueOf(size));
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onScaleEnd(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        relative.onTouchEvent(event);
        return true;
    }
}
}
```

XML code:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/sv">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/article"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your gesture, right now your `TextView` is grabbing complete available space. So you have to setup gesture on `TextView`.

```
public class sukharta extends Activity {

    TextView scaleGesture;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content_main);
        scaleGesture = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.article);
        scaleGesture.setText("25");
        scaleGesture.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

        // ******Set gesture on your TextView******
        scaleGesture.setOnTouchListener(new simpleOnScaleGestureListener(this));

    }


    public class simpleOnScaleGestureListener implements View.OnTouchListener,
            ScaleGestureDetector.OnScaleGestureListener {

        private ScaleGestureDetector gestureScale;

        public simpleOnScaleGestureListener(Context context) {
            gestureScale = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, this);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            gestureScale = detector;

            float size = scaleGesture.getTextSize();
            Log.d("TextSizeStart", String.valueOf(size));

            float factor = detector.getScaleFactor();
            Log.d("Factor", String.valueOf(factor));


            float product = size * factor;
            Log.d("TextSize", String.valueOf(product));
            scaleGesture.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, product);

            size = scaleGesture.getTextSize();
            Log.d("TextSizeEnd", String.valueOf(size));
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onScaleEnd(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            gestureScale.onTouchEvent(event);
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

Note - Small suggestion, start your class name from capital character, try to avoid inner classes and focus on single responsibility classes design.

Comment: thank you for your reply. Doing so has solved the querry but now scroll doesnot work. @Rahul

Comment: I appreciate it works for you, you could accept answer if it works for you

Comment: Do you mean ScrollView.

Comment: yes, scaleGesture.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150433/discussion-between-devk-and-rahul).

Comment: instead of using relative layout if I use Scrollview the scroll works but zoom gives problem like I have zoom vertically, sometimes does not work.

Comment: instead of using relative layout if I use Scrollview the scroll works but zoom gives problem like I have zoom vertically, sometimes does not work.